# My jQuery custom autocomplete focus/select ui item refer to the source not to the item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I encountered an issue on the options select and focus of a custom autocomplete of jQuery. The `ui.item` should select the item selected but it selects data from the source.

I searched on Google and I can't find anyone with the same issue as me. Apart from this the code works fine. How can I fix the problem?

```js
$("#RefProductHome").catcomplete({
  source: data,
  delay: 0,
  focus: function(e, ui) {
    console.log(ui.item) // => data
  }
});
```

Order of the script:
1- Création custom catcomplete
2- Get data from two different api
3- Merge in two result i

1. Création custom catcomplete
2. Get data from two different api
3. Merge the two result from api in data
4. Start catcomplete()

Comment: What is `catcomplete()`? It's not part of jQuery or jQueryUI

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and also provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Currently, we are unable to replicate the issue.

Comment: catcomplete() is a custom autocomplete,  https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories